# How to spread a single column into wide format with 0 and 1 as values defined conditionally?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

How can I convert my column "payment" from long to wide format while keeping the other columns unchanged?

For each level of "letter", when the cell is before the value of "payment", then when in the wide format this row of the corresponding new variable "e.g., dollar" will have "0"; otherwise "1".

I tried `output_format_test<-input_format%>%tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = age, values_from = payment)`, but it does not produce the intended result.

##Input format

```
input_format <- readr::read_table2("letter age payment
    A 2 NA
    A 3 dollar
    A 4 NA
    D 2 euro
    D 3 dollar
    D 4 NA
    F 2 NA
    F 3 euro
    F 3 dollar
    F 4 NA
    F 4 NA")
    
input_format 
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   letter   age payment
   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  
 1 A          2 NA     
 2 A          3 dollar 
 3 A          4 NA     
 4 D          2 euro   
 5 D          3 dollar 
 6 D          4 NA     
 7 F          2 NA     
 8 F          3 euro   
 9 F          3 dollar 
10 F          4 NA     
11 F          4 NA
```

##output format

```
output_format <- readr::read_table2(
"letter age payment dollar euro
A 2 NA 0 0
A 3 dollar 1 0
A 4 NA 1 0
D 2 euro 0 1
D 3 dollar 1 1
D 4 NA 1 1
F 2 NA 0 0
F 3 euro 0 1
F 3 dollar 1 1
F 4 NA 1 1
F 4 NA 1 1
")
    
output_format
# A tibble: 11 x 5
   letter   age payment dollar  euro
   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A          2 NA           0     0
 2 A          3 dollar       1     0
 3 A          4 NA           1     0
 4 D          2 euro         0     1
 5 D          3 dollar       1     1
 6 D          4 NA           1     1
 7 F          2 NA           0     0
 8 F          3 euro         0     1
 9 F          3 dollar       1     1
10 F          4 NA           1     1
11 F          4 NA           1     1
```

Thanks. Edited.

Comment: In output, is `6 D          4 NA           1     1` correct?

Comment: Yes. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Could you kindly reword this explanation: _For each level of "letter", when the cell is before the value of "payment", then when in the wide format this row of the corresponding new variable "e.g., dollar)" will have "0"; otherwise "1"."_ . It is really difficult to understand what you mean.

Comment: Regardless, the `output_format` shows clearly the desired transformation.

Comment: Your expected output is not a simple long-format wide-format conversion. It is not clear to me how `NA` values should be transformed. In some cases they are coded as `0` In others as `1` what’s the rule?

Comment: The rule is: `For each level of "letter", when the cell is before the value of "payment", then when in the wide format this row of the corresponding new variable "e.g., dollar)" will have "0"; otherwise "1". That plus the out_format should be clear to see what is the desired output.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

input_format %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = payment, values_from = payment, 
              values_fn = length) %>%
  select(- c(id, `NA`)) %>%
  bind_cols(input_format$payment) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., "\\.\\.\\.\\d+", "payment"), contains(fixed("..."))) %>%
  relocate(letter, age, payment) %>%
  group_by(letter) %>%
  replace_na(list(dollar = 0, euro = 0)) %>%
  mutate(across(dollar:euro, ~ cummax(.x))) -> input2


# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   letter [3]
   letter   age payment dollar  euro
   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A          2 NA           0     0
 2 A          3 dollar       1     0
 3 A          4 NA           1     0
 4 D          2 euro         0     1
 5 D          3 dollar       1     1
 6 D          4 NA           1     1
 7 F          2 NA           0     0
 8 F          3 euro         0     1
 9 F          3 dollar       1     1
10 F          4 NA           1     1
11 F          4 NA           1     1
```

After discussion in the comment you can use the following solution to get your desired output:

```
input2 %>%
  group_by(letter, age) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  group_by(letter, age) %>%
  filter((n == 2 & if_all(dollar:euro, ~ .x == 1)) | n == 1) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  group_by(letter, age) %>%
  add_count() %>%
  group_split(letter, age) %>%
  map_dfr(~ if(.x$n[1] == 2) {
    .x %>% slice_tail(n = 1)
  } else {
    .x
  })

# A tibble: 9 x 6
  letter   age payment dollar  euro     n
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 A          2 NA           0     0     1
2 A          3 dollar       1     0     1
3 A          4 NA           1     0     1
4 D          2 euro         0     1     1
5 D          3 dollar       1     1     1
6 D          4 NA           1     1     1
7 F          2 NA           0     0     1
8 F          3 dollar       1     1     1
9 F          4 NA           1     1     2
```

Comment: `Error in rename(., payment = ...5) : unused argument (payment = ...5)`

Comment: Oh I got it. You should remove `.` from the first argument of `rename`. It's not necessary.

Comment: Oh my pleasure. Glad it helped.

Comment: This is the only approach that worked with my actual data: `when a payment method is mentioned more than once per group.`

Comment: However, would it be possible to automate the determination of the number `5` here: `rename(payment = ...5). `?

Comment: I add `payment` column from the original data set and because it was going to be the fifth column to the output it was renamed `...5` by `bind_cols`. Would you please explain a bit how would you like to automate it?

Comment: When applying to my actual data, I needed to change `rename(payment = ...5)` to the `rename(payment = ...new_number)`, where `new_number` is the new number of columns. But for large datasets, that is prone to errors.

Comment: Ok check my updates. I replaced that line of code with `rename_with` in case you don't want to refer to any number explicitly like `5` here.

Comment: Additionally, would it be possible to collapse the rows for same  `letter` and `age` to keep only the row where all elements of that `letter` and `age` have `1`?

Comment: Meaning you would like only five rows to remain of the above result? What happened to the previous problem? You got the naming right?

Comment: That is: for `letter = F & age = 3` keep only line 9?

Comment: What about `letter = F & age = 4` ?

Comment: Thanks. The same. That is: for `letter = F & age = 3` keep only line 9; for `letter = F & age = 4` keep only line 11?

Comment: I will modify that part shortly. No problem.

Comment: Renaming worked. Thanks. Any thoughts about: for `letter = F & age = 3` keep only line 9; for `letter = F & age = 4` keep only line 11?

Comment: Checked. Worked great. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Tidyverse approach

```r
input_format <- readr::read_table2("letter age payment
    A 2 NA
    A 3 dollar
    A 4 NA
    D 2 euro
    D 3 dollar
    D 4 NA
    F 2 NA
    F 3 euro
    F 3 dollar
    F 4 NA
    F 4 NA")

library(tidyverse)

input_format %>% mutate(rowid = row_number(),
                        payment1 = payment,
                        dummy = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -c(payment1, dummy), names_from = payment1, values_from = dummy, values_fill = 0, values_fn = length) %>%
  select(-`NA`) %>%
  group_by(letter) %>%
  mutate(across(c('dollar', 'euro'), cumsum))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 6
#> # Groups:   letter [3]
#>    letter   age payment rowid dollar  euro
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>   <int>  <int> <int>
#>  1 A          2 <NA>        1      0     0
#>  2 A          3 dollar      2      1     0
#>  3 A          4 <NA>        3      1     0
#>  4 D          2 euro        4      0     1
#>  5 D          3 dollar      5      1     1
#>  6 D          4 <NA>        6      1     1
#>  7 F          2 <NA>        7      0     0
#>  8 F          3 euro        8      0     1
#>  9 F          3 dollar      9      1     1
#> 10 F          4 <NA>       10      1     1
#> 11 F          4 <NA>       11      1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: got it.  Check now @Krantz

Comment: Further edited to match exactly as yours @Krantz

Answer (score 2):

using zoo (and data.table but not required):

```
input_format <- fread("letter age payment
     A 2 NA
     A 3 dollar
     A 4 NA
     D 2 euro
     D 3 dollar
     D 4 NA
     F 2 NA
     F 3 euro
     F 3 dollar
     F 4 NA
     F 4 NA")

output_format <- copy(input_format)[payment == "dollar", dollar := 1][, dollar := na.locf0(dollar), by=.(letter)]
output_format[payment == "euro", euro := 1][, euro := na.locf0(euro), by=.(letter)]
output_format[, c("dollar", "euro")][is.na(output_format[, c("dollar", "euro")])] <- 0
```

which produces:

```
 > output_format
    letter age payment dollar euro
 1:      A   2    <NA>      0    0
 2:      A   3  dollar      1    0
 3:      A   4    <NA>      1    0
 4:      D   2    euro      0    1
 5:      D   3  dollar      1    1
 6:      D   4    <NA>      1    1
 7:      F   2    <NA>      0    0
 8:      F   3    euro      0    1
 9:      F   3  dollar      1    1
10:      F   4    <NA>      1    1
11:      F   4    <NA>      1    1
```

Comment: `Error in `[.tbl_df`(input_format, payment == "dollar", `:=`(dollar, 1)) : 
  object 'payment' not found`

Comment: I suspect you don't have data.table loaded? If you are using regular data.frames you will need to change the language a bit to make it work

Answer (score 2):

To add another approach:

We could use `map_dfc` and `set_names` to loop over a named vector of `payment`s.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

input_format %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(unique(.$payment) %>% set_names(., .),
                 ~ cumsum(!(payment != .x | is.na(payment)))
  )) %>% 
  select(- `...1`)

#> New names:
#> * NA -> ...1
#> New names:
#> * NA -> ...1
#> New names:
#> * NA -> ...1
#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#> # Groups:   letter [3]
#>    letter   age payment dollar  euro
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <int> <int>
#>  1 A          2 <NA>         0     0
#>  2 A          3 dollar       1     0
#>  3 A          4 <NA>         1     0
#>  4 D          2 euro         0     1
#>  5 D          3 dollar       1     1
#>  6 D          4 <NA>         1     1
#>  7 F          2 <NA>         0     0
#>  8 F          3 euro         0     1
#>  9 F          3 dollar       1     1
#> 10 F          4 <NA>         1     1
#> 11 F          4 <NA>         1     1
```

We could simplify the code above with a package I have on github and use `over` instead of `map_dfc` and `dist_values` instead of `unique`

```r
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

input_format %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(over(dist_values(.$payment),
              ~ cumsum(!(payment != .x | is.na(payment)))
              ))

#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#> # Groups:   letter [3]
#>    letter   age payment dollar  euro
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A          2 <NA>         0     0
#>  2 A          3 dollar       1     0
#>  3 A          4 <NA>         1     0
#>  4 D          2 euro         0     1
#>  5 D          3 dollar       1     1
#>  6 D          4 <NA>         1     1
#>  7 F          2 <NA>         0     0
#>  8 F          3 euro         0     1
#>  9 F          3 dollar       1     1
#> 10 F          4 <NA>         1     1
#> 11 F          4 <NA>         1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, neither my answer nor the accepted answer by @AnilGoyal can handle data when a payment method is mentioned more than once per group. I don't know if the desired answer should account for this case. At the moment only the answers by @Wietse de Vries and @Anoushiravan R work  with this kind of data:

```r
input_format <- readr::read_table2("letter age payment
    A 2 NA
    A 3 dollar
    A 4 NA
    A 5 dollar # this line is new
    D 2 euro
    D 3 dollar
    D 4 NA
    F 2 NA
    F 3 euro
    F 3 dollar
    F 4 NA
    F 4 NA")
```

We could easily adjust the approach above as follows to account for this case:

```r
input_format %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(over(dist_values(.$payment),
              ~ ifelse(
                  cumsum(!(payment != .x | is.na(payment))) >= 1,
                  1, 0)
  ))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#> # Groups:   letter [3]
#>    letter   age payment dollar  euro
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A          2 <NA>         0     0
#>  2 A          3 dollar       1     0
#>  3 A          4 <NA>         1     0
#>  4 A          5 dollar       1     0
#>  5 D          2 euro         0     1
#>  6 D          3 dollar       1     1
#>  7 D          4 <NA>         1     1
#>  8 F          2 <NA>         0     0
#>  9 F          3 euro         0     1
#> 10 F          3 dollar       1     1
#> 11 F          4 <NA>         1     1
#> 12 F          4 <NA>         1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Great. The last aproach gives this error: `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = over(...)`.
x could not find function "over"
...
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Additionally: `Error: Failed to install 'dplyover' from GitHub:
  'local_makevars' is not an exported object from 'namespace:withr'`

Comment: Interesting error, I haven't encountered yet. Alternatively you could use the `ifelse(cumsum(...))` inside the `map_dfc` approach outlined above.

Comment: @Krantz: I added your error as an [issue](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover/issues/10). It would be great if you could give me some information about your session (R version, etc.) so I can try to track the error down.

Comment: Thank you for the kind notes. I really appreciate it.